# Quick help, scale_color_manual is not showing legend for multiple line

Tags: r

I have search variously on stackoverflow and tried the solution, but I still can't get it to work

here is my code

```
create_all_project_figure <- function(all_agg_table, all_scale, heavy_j, heavy_v, light_j, light_v, output_title, pic_title) {
  colors <- c("Heavy J Gene" = "violet", "Heavy V Gene" = "orange", "Light J Gene" = "pink", "Light V Gene" = "blue")
  max_count = max(all_agg_table$count)
  max_diff = max(all_agg_table$mean)
  if (max_count<500){break_point = 25}
  else if(max_count>500 & max_count<1000) {break_point = 50}
  else if (max_count>1000 & max_count<2000) {break_point = 100}
  else if (max_count>2000 & max_count<4000) {break_point = 200}
  else {break_point = 500}
  if (max_diff<10){break_point_mutation = 1}
  else if(max_diff>10 & max_diff<20) {break_point_mutation = 2}
  else {break_point_mutation = 3}
  #png(paste(output_directory, output_title, sep = "/"), height = 1040, width = 1920)
  plot <- ggplot(data =all_agg_table, aes(x=all_agg_table$harvest, width = 0.8, colour = colors)) +geom_bar(aes(y=all_agg_table$count), stat="identity", fill='lightgreen', color = 'green')+
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_j$mean*all_scale), color = 'violet', size=1) + geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_j$mean*all_scale), color = 'purple', size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_v$mean*all_scale), color = 'orange', size=1) + geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_v$mean*all_scale), color = 'yellow', size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=light_j$mean*all_scale), color = 'pink', size=1) + geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=light_j$mean*all_scale), color = 'red', size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=light_v$mean*all_scale), color = 'blue', size=1) + geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=light_v$mean*all_scale), color = 'black', size=2)+
    scale_y_continuous(name="Count of samples",  breaks =seq(0, max_count+100, by = break_point),sec.axis = sec_axis(~./all_scale, name="% Mutation from Germline",  breaks = seq(0, max_diff+2, by = break_point_mutation))) +
    scale_x_discrete(name="Project")+  ggtitle(pic_title) +
    scale_color_manual(name ='legend', values = c("Heavy J Gene" = "violet", "Heavy V Gene" = "orange", "Light J Gene" = "pink", "Light V Gene" = "blue"))+
    labs(color = 'Y series')+
    theme(text = element_text(size=30),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70,hjust=1,vjust=1),
          axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="darkgreen", face="bold"),
          axis.title.y.right=element_text(color="red"),
          axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-0.7))
  print(plot)
  #dev.off()
}
```

can anyone help me and see why the legend is not showing?

Thanks

Comment: Put the color inside the `aes()` call.

Comment: ... and instead of using e.g. `color="violet"` use `color="Heavy J Gene"` and so on. Otherwise you won't get any colors.

Comment: Thank you guys, ah so just put inside aes()

Answer (score 1):

This should work but I am not able to test as no data was shared. Take into account what colleages **@stefan** and **@DaveArmstrong** suggested:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Function
create_all_project_figure <- function(all_agg_table, all_scale,
                                      heavy_j, heavy_v, light_j,
                                      light_v, output_title, pic_title) {
  colors <- c("Heavy J Gene" = "violet", "Heavy V Gene" = "orange", "Light J Gene" = "pink", "Light V Gene" = "blue")
  max_count = max(all_agg_table$count)
  max_diff = max(all_agg_table$mean)
  if (max_count<500){break_point = 25}
  else if(max_count>500 & max_count<1000) {break_point = 50}
  else if (max_count>1000 & max_count<2000) {break_point = 100}
  else if (max_count>2000 & max_count<4000) {break_point = 200}
  else {break_point = 500}
  if (max_diff<10){break_point_mutation = 1}
  else if(max_diff>10 & max_diff<20) {break_point_mutation = 2}
  else {break_point_mutation = 3}
  #png(paste(output_directory, output_title, sep = "/"), height = 1040, width = 1920)
  plot <- ggplot(data =all_agg_table, aes(x=all_agg_table$harvest, width = 0.8, colour = colors)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y=all_agg_table$count, color = 'green'), stat="identity", fill='lightgreen')+
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_j$mean*all_scale, color = 'violet'), size=1) +
    geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_j$mean*all_scale, color = 'purple'), size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_v$mean*all_scale, color = 'orange'), size=1) +
    geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=heavy_v$mean*all_scale, color = 'yellow'), size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=light_j$mean*all_scale, color = 'pink'), size=1) +
    geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=light_j$mean*all_scale, color = 'red'), size=2)+ 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1, y=light_v$mean*all_scale, color = 'blue'), size=1) + 
    geom_point(aes(group = 1, y=light_v$mean*all_scale, color = 'black'), size=2)+
    scale_y_continuous(name="Count of samples",
                       breaks =seq(0, max_count+100, by = break_point),
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~./all_scale,
                                           name="% Mutation from Germline", 
                                           breaks = seq(0, max_diff+2,
                                                        by = break_point_mutation))) +
    scale_x_discrete(name="Project")+  ggtitle(pic_title) +
    scale_color_manual(name ='legend',
                       values = c("Heavy J Gene" = "violet", "Heavy V Gene" = "orange", "Light J Gene" = "pink", "Light V Gene" = "blue"))+
    labs(color = 'Y series')+
    theme(text = element_text(size=30),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70,hjust=1,vjust=1),
          axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="darkgreen", face="bold"),
          axis.title.y.right=element_text(color="red"),
          axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-0.7))
  print(plot)
  #dev.off()
}
```